# How can I create a windows service ACS by powershell? The server failed to authneticate the request

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus

So, I downloaded the azure powershell because I wanted to create a service bus namespace with an attached ACS by powershell, something that apparently cant be done anymore via the UI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170478.aspx

Service Bus authentication through ACS is managed through a companion “-sb” ACS namespace. If you want a companion ACS namespace to be created for a Service Bus namespace, create your Service Bus namespace using the New-AzureSBNamespace PowerShell cmdlet. For example:
Windows PowerShell

```
New-AzureSBNamespace <namespaceName> "<Region>”
```

For example, if you create a Service Bus namespace called contoso.servicebus.windows.net, a companion ACS namespace called contoso-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net is provisioned automatically. For all namespaces that were created before August 2014, an accompanying ACS namespace was created.

So, what I did is:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

This made me download a file and then I used:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile –PublishSettingsFile "C:\Users\valencil\Google Drive\Tools\Pay-As-You-Go-9-5-2014-credentials.publishsettings"
```

The import didnt throw any error, however when I tried:

```
New-AzureSBNamespace "levalencia" "West-Europe”
```

I got this error:

```
New-AzureSBNamespace : ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this 
subscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureSBNamespace "levalencia" "West-Europe”
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBNamespace], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBNamespaceCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set/select the subscription before you issue the new-azuresbnamespace command.

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName

Comment: that doesnt exist. maybe u meant this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722501.aspx

Comment: I think you're missing some of the azure powershell bits as select-azuresubscription does indeed exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495203.aspx I also just verified the presence of this cmdlet on my own machine (which has Azure Powershell 8.7.1)

Comment: it worked for me with set, my bus name was wrong, I suppose SET and SELECT do the same? http://screencast.com/t/Mwp3f9Ithir

Comment: select-azuresubscription, i think you mean